# highlighting lines based on array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a body of text with several lines.  Each line is wrapped in a span with an incremented value at the end to determine which line is what (for example, line-1, line-2, line-3 and so forth).

```
<div id="textbody">
    <span id="line-1">what is love</span><br/>
    <span id="line-2">oh baby, don't hurt me</span><br/>
    <span id="line-3">Don't hurt me no more</span><br/>
    <span id="line-4">Oh, baby don't hurt me</span><br/>
    <span id="line-5">Don't hurt me no more</span><br/>
    <span id="line-6">What is love</span><br/>
    <span id="line-7">Yeah</span><br/>
</div>
```

Now I have an array that says lines 1 and 2 are grouped together and lines 5-6 are grouped together.  Which means when the mouse hovers over line-1 then turn the background a different color on line-1 and line-2 (as per the array) as well as if line-5 is mouseovered then do the background thing on line-5 and line-6.

It's simply doing it on a span by span basis, but I'm not sure how to approach the array part of it.  Should I use something like in_array?  I know it's a PHP function, but Google tells me people have built similar functions for JS.

```
$("span[id^='line-']").live('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var line_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(6);

  $(this).addClass("highlight1");

  return false;
}); 

$("span[id^='line-']").live('mouseleave', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var line_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(6);

  $(this).removeClass("highlight1");

  return false;
});
```

Comment: How is structured your array?

Comment: I guess that is the other thing.  I wasn't sure if I should do an array like ("1,2","5,6") or do a multidimensional.

Comment: Do you have freedom to change the HTML?

Answer (score 4):

If you can group the elements in the HTML:

```
<div id="textbody">
  <span>
    <span>what is love</span><br/>
    <span>oh baby, don't hurt me</span><br/>
  </span>
  <span>Don't hurt me no more</span><br/>
  <span>Oh, baby don't hurt me</span><br/>
  <span>
    <span>Don't hurt me no more</span><br/>
    <span>What is love</span><br/>
  </span>
  <span>Yeah</span><br/>
</div>
```

Then you don't need any script at all, just some CSS:

```
#textbody > span:hover { background: yellow; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Rfwye/

Comment: didn't even think about going it like this!  thanks for the suggestion (and thinking outside the box!)

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = [{
    group: [1,2],
    color: "#000"},
{
    group: [3,7],
    color: "#0ff"},
{
    group: [4,6],
    color: "#ff0"},
{
    group: [5],
    color: "#ff0000"}];

$(groups).each(function(index, item) {
    $(item.group).each(function(i, span) {
        $("#line-" + span).addClass("group" + index).data("bgcolor", item.color);
    });
});

$("#textbody span").mouseover(function(){
   $("." + $(this).attr("class")).css("background-color", $(this).data("bgcolor"));
});

$("#textbody span").mouseout(function(){
   $("." + $(this).attr("class")).css("background", "transparent");
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/y8UrW/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the container and use CSS to highlight lines based on the hovered over line.

```
$('#textbody').addClass('over-' + $(this).id());
```

and then use CSS to group them

```css
#textbody span[id^='line-']:hover, /* Always highlight the hovered line */
.over-line-1 > #line-2, .over-line-2 > #line-1 /* Higlight the partner line */
{ background: yellow }
```

will group lines 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a somewhat lengthy solution that maintains your current structure. Seems to work well, though it might be a little overkill for your case... Anyway, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Ap6JP/

```
var groups = [
  [1, 2],
  [5, 6]
]

var lineIdFor = function($span) {
  return parseInt($span.attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0]);  
};

var groupFor = function(lineId) {
  var group;
  $.each(groups, function() {
    if(this.indexOf(lineId) >= 0) {
      group = this;
    }
  });

  return group || [lineId];
};

var spansInGroup = function(group) {
  var $spans = new $();

  $.each(group, function() {
    $spans = $spans.add($("#line-" + this));
  });

  return $spans;
};

var groupForSpan = function($span) {
  var lineId = lineIdFor($span);
  var group  = groupFor(lineId);
  return spansInGroup(group);
};

$("#textbody").on("mouseover", "span", function() {
  var $group = groupForSpan($(this));
  $group.addClass("highlight1");
});

$("#textbody").on("mouseout", "span", function() {
  var $group = groupForSpan($(this));
  $group.removeClass("highlight1");
});​
```